# Performance of separate SQL commands versus a single stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I've inherited some code that interfaces with GP. While reviewing the code prior to debugging an issue I found a function that undoes updates to a set of tables.

The code contains a number of SQL commands and I was wondering if I would get better performance from a single stored procedure with an input parameter that is the table **ds** than running all these commands on each row of the table separately.

```
    private void revertSave()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = GetConnectionToGP();
            if (conn != null)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    //records from InventoryTransaction Master, Detail, and Serial tables when window is opened.
                    foreach (DataRow dr in _ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        //TRANSACTION tables
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE InventoryTransaction_Master " +
                            "SET Completed = 0 WHERE DocumentNumber = " + SqlString(dr["DocumentNumber"].ToString().Trim());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE InventoryTransaction_Serial " +
                            "SET BIN = '' " +
                            "WHERE DocumentNumber = " + SqlString(dr["DocumentNumber"].ToString().Trim()) +
                            " and DocumentType = 1 and ItemNumber = " + SqlString(dr["PrefixedItemNumber"].ToString().Trim()) +
                            " and LineSequenceNumber = " + SqlString(dr["LineSequenceNumber"].ToString().Trim()) +
                            " and SerialNumber = " + SqlString(dr["SerialNumber"].ToString().Trim());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //TRANSFER tables
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT detail.DocumentNumber " +
                            "FROM  InventoryTransfer_Detail detail " +
                            "INNER JOIN InventoryTransfer_Serial serial ON detail.DocumentNumber = serial.DocumentNumber " +
                            "and detail.ItemNumber = serial.ItemNumber " +
                            "and detail.LineSequenceNumber = serial.LineSequenceNumber " +
                            "WHERE SessionID = " + SqlString(dr["SessionID"].ToString().Trim()) +
                            " and SerialNumber = " + SqlString(dr["SerialNumber"].ToString().Trim());
                        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE InventoryTransfer_Master " +
                                "SET Completed = 0 WHERE DocumentNumber = " + SqlString(obj.ToString());
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE InventoryTransfer_Serial " +
                                "SET OriginalBin = '', NewBin = '' " +
                                "WHERE DocumentNumber = " + SqlString(obj.ToString()) + " and SerialNumber = " + SqlString(dr["SerialNumber"].ToString().Trim());
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
            }

            //this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ELog el = new ELog(ex, CLASS_NAME + " revertSave");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The biggest concern with the code there is SQL injection, but that doesn't mean that stored procedures are the answer. Parameters are a separate topic.

Comment: There is a false dichotomy between "the code shown" and "stored procedures"; you can get all the same performance characteristics of stored procedures using *correctly parameterized commands*, noting that a single `CommandText` can still perform multiple TSQL operations; some lengthy reading on the topic: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html

Comment: @MarcGravell It is an application running in terminal server behind a firewall, not a web application.

Comment: In addition to a fully parameterized stored proc or batch, you probably want to enclose the statements in a transaction to ensure all-or-none. That will also improve performance due to less logging.

Comment: @pacmaninbw that doesn't change a single thing I said :) if you don't think SQL injection applies to internal systems, then ... you need to rethink that; besides which, everything I said about performance applies *whatever* your approach to SQL injection

Comment: @pacmaninbw Since there is no apparent transaction handling, a failure will leave the database in an unexpected state. The "select distinct" logic is problematic since it's executed as scalar. Perhaps you should concentrate less on efficiency and more on correctness. And if this code "works", you should seriously consider leaving it alone. Don't fix problems that do not exist. Don't optimize things that don't **need** optimization. You touch it, you own it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to predict performance of complex systems without actually trying it out, but it is highly likely that a stored procedure would improve the speed of execution, especially if your dataset is large.

With your current method you have

- Four SQL commands per row. So for 1,000 rows, there will be 4,000 commands.
- 4,000 network hops
- 4,000 instances of single-row locks
- 4,000 SQL compilation events

With a stored procedure, you could theoretically have

- Three SQL commands, total, that correlate all the rows necessary for fetching the necessary values. While these would be very complicated statements (with lots of joins), 3 is much less than 4,000.
- One network hop
- One transaction, containing all of the necessary row, page, or potentially table locks.
- No compilation events at all, if the stored procedure is compiled ahead of time.

Everything looks much better with the stored procedure, except the potential for greater locking. Depending on your overall solution, that lock could be a deal-breaker, as it could block other processes for other users who are trying to do the same thing at the same time.

There's also some devilish details-- for example, updating one row at a time could potentially be more efficient than doing a mass update, if the table is massive and has many rows that you are not updating, and the bulk update triggers table scans instead of index seeks. However, a good SQL developer can tailor the SQL queries and commands to nudge SQL Server in the right direction.

TLDR: In most cases, the stored procedure will give you better performance.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, SQL injection and transactions are issues.  Other potential issues with this code are maintainability (ease of typing AND ease of finding AND ease of debugging).  Any of these issues may well be more important than the performance.  It looks like it could be doing more row-based logic than set-based logic, which is usually a performance problem.  If it is customary in the company to build SQL in the code, and this runs in an amount of time which is not burdensome to the systems or to the people running it, it is possibly the best place for it (leaving aside the threat of SQL injection).

If this is causing actual performance problems, it should be optimized, and the best way to optimize is to test.  Does it run in 5 minutes this way?  When you convert it to a stored proc, does it the take 1 minute?  How about when you remove the loop, and make it entirely set-based logic?

Comment: It is customary in the code to call stored procedures. There are performance issues in production. Your suggestion for performance testing a good one, and I will do it if the boss lets me. Thank you for your answer.